# How to replace only 0 values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle10g

I have a table that i want to replace all instances where the value is zero. However, the code I am running also replaces values that contain zero in it, for example, 403 & 4004. It will replace it to 43 & 44. is there a way to just replace values of zero only?

**Here is my table:**

```
id | value
1,    0
2,    0
3,    4004
4,    404
```

**here is what i want the output to look like:**

```
id | value
1,    -
2,    -
3,    4004
4,    404
```

**here is my code:**

```
select replace(value, '0', '-') as new_value from table1;
```

My output looks like this which is not what I want:

```
id | value
1,    -
2,    -
3,    4--4
4,    4-4
```

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value = '0' then '-' else value end)
from t;
```

This assumes that `value` is a string.  If not, you need to convert it:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value = '0' then '-' else cast(value as varchar2(255)) end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter option uses [`DECODE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function proper to Oracle DB such as

```
SELECT DECODE(value,0,'-',value)
  FROM tab
```

where no need to quote the zero presuming `value` is a numeric column.

Comment: do you know how to add them now?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Check out the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=626e986769e579727c17502ed2088073) @mali_the please